# Add String variable to a Linked list?

Tags: java, javafx, linked-list

I am making a program that returns the output in a long string variable. The data in the string is constantly changing based on what the user enters in the GUI. My question is, how do I take this and store it inside of my linked list? I have looked at a few examples, but the class I was provided with for my class is a little different, and I haven't been able to find something to specifically fix my problem.

Controller Code:

```
public class RentGameDialogController extends RentalStoreGUIController implements Initializable{

/** TextField Objects **/
@FXML private TextField nameField, rentedOnField, dueBackField;

/** String for NameField **/
String name, rentedOn, dueBack;

/** Game ComboBox ID's **/
@FXML private ObservableList<GameType> cbGameOptions;
@FXML private ComboBox<GameType> cbGame;

/** Console ComboBox ID's **/
@FXML private ObservableList<PlayerType> cbConsoleOptions;
@FXML private ComboBox<PlayerType> cbConsole;

/** GameType object **/
private GameType game;

/** PlayerType Object **/
private PlayerType console;

/** Button ID's **/
@FXML Button cancel, addToCart;

/** Counter for calculating total **/
int gameCounter;

/** Stage for closing GUI **/
private Stage currentStage;

private MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();




@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    /** Select Console **/
    cbConsoleOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (PlayerType p : PlayerType.values()) { cbConsoleOptions.addAll(p); }
    cbConsole.getItems().addAll(cbConsoleOptions);

    /** Select Game **/
    cbGameOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (GameType g : GameType.values()){ cbGameOptions.addAll(g); }
    cbGame.getItems().addAll(cbGameOptions);

}

public String getName(){
    name = nameField.getText();

    try {

        String[] firstLast = name.split(" ");
        String firstName = firstLast[0];
        String lastName = firstLast[1];

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return name;
}

public String getGame() {
    return cbGame.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
}

public String getConsole() {
    return cbConsole.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
}

public String getRentedOn() throws ParseException {

    rentedOn = rentedOnField.getText();


    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date rentedOnDate = format.parse(rentedOn);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setLenient(false);
    cal.setTime(rentedOnDate);

    try {

        cal.getTime();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        rentedOnField.setText("ERROR");
    }

    return rentedOn;

}

public String getDueBack() throws ParseException {

    dueBack = dueBackField.getText();


    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dueBackDate = format.parse(dueBack);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setLenient(false);
    cal.setTime(dueBackDate);

    try {

        cal.getTime();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        dueBackField.setText("ERROR");
    }

    return dueBack;

}

/*************************************
 * This is the method to call the other
 * String methods so their output can be
 * put into my main GUI
 *
 *
 * @return
 * @throws ParseException
 *************************************/

public String storePurchaseData() throws ParseException {
    gameCounter++;
    String toList = getName() + " | " + getGame() + " | " + getConsole() + " | " +
            getRentedOn() + " | " + getDueBack();

    //Add 'toList' to the linked list here if possible

    return toList;
}


@FXML
public void handleCancelButtonAction () {
    currentStage = (Stage) cancel.getScene().getWindow();
    currentStage.close();
}

@FXML
public void addToCartButton () throws ParseException {
    appendTextArea(storePurchaseData());
    currentStage = (Stage) cancel.getScene().getWindow();
    currentStage.close();
}}
```

This code is for my controller. It launches a basic GUI, then I can pull the data from all of the fields I made, convert them to Strings and can then print them in one long chain of text. I would like to store the string into my linked list class.

Linked List code:

```
public class MyLinkedList<E> implements Serializable {

private DNode<E> top;
public int size;

public MyLinkedList() {
    top = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

}

I am very new to linked lists and I am trying to understand them, does this code make sense? Do I need to add anything to, say, save the String that I am storing into a text file?

Thank you in advance

Comment: One possible problem I see, you're not initializing the variable `top` in the `MyLinkedList` class.

Comment: Consider providing a [_Minimal_, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't feel like sifting through all your code to find the relevant bit

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into your game code at all, it looks like your `MyLinkedList` class takes a type parameter `E` - You haven't shown the code for `DNode` but it also takes the `E` type. If you can specify this to be a `String` then the nodes of `MyLinkedList` can be populated with Strings as you desire.

```
DNode<String> myFirstNode = new DNode<>(null, null, "nodeData");
MyLinkedList<String> list = new MyLinkedList<>(myFirstNode);
```

This assumes that the `MyLinkedList` class also has a constructor that takes a `DNode` to initialize its `head`, and that `DNode` looks something like [this](http://www.augustana.ualberta.ca/~hackw/csc210/exhibit/chap06/DNode.java).

Comment: Hint: it should read `new DNode<>(...`  otherwise you are creating a **raw type**, and that would be worth a downvote; and similarly, you dont need the typename for new new MyLinkedList ... the empty diamond operator does that job!

Comment: Thank you... it has been a while since I wrote any Java!